# Exclude folder from redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Wordpress redirects everything in wp-content if accessed directly to 404 with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What I want to do is not redirect the contents of a sub folder `example.com/wp-content/uploads/event/images/`

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Insert an ignore/skip rule before WP front controller rule. Insert this just below `RewriteBase` line:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(index\.php$|wp-content/uploads/event/images/) - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```